# compress list of files and directories with brotli

Tags: compression, brotli

I'd like to use [brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli) to compress a list of files and directories. I'm able to do this with zip running

```
zip -r  archive.zip *
```

and I'm looking for a similar command with brotli. I've tried

```
tar -cf archive.gz * && \
brotli -n -q 11 -o archive.zip archive.gz
```

but after decompression the zip doesn't have the same structure than with zip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second command is actually right. Brotli, like Gzip/Bzip2/etc can only compress a single file.

What you must do is first package all of your files in a tarball:

```sh
tar -cvf output.tar /path/to/dir
```

And then compress the resulting tarball with Brotli:

```sh
brotli -j -Z output.tar
```

Which should leave you with a `output.tar.br` file (similar to `*.tar.gz` gzipped tarballs).

Answer (score 2):

Either of these commands will work to create a brotli compressed tar file without an intermediate tar file:

1. Directly using `tar` with the option `--use-compress-program`

   ```bash
   tar -cvf test-output.tar.br --use-compress-program="brotli -Z" ./my_data_to_compress
   ```
2. Piping to `brotli`

   ```bash
   tar --create --verbose ./my_data_to_compress | brotli --output=compressed_files.tar.br
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Brotli-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brotli-cli)?

This comes with a lot of options to get files compressed using Brotli

Answer (score -1):

you can try creating a .tar file instead of .gz

Comment: Please elaborate, why does that help?

Comment: I thought he was trying to compress an already compressed file (gzip), which won't work.. but now I realized he's only naming as .gz (missing z parameter), so it's just a tarball .gz suffixed.. should work